# Как сделать такую таблицу?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать данную таблицу, хотя бы на идею наткните

Вот таблица:
[image: Table]

Comment: уберите ссылку на картинке и вставьте её исходник в вопрос.

Comment: Она не загружалась на imgur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `display: grid;`

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.table-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с `display: inline-block;`

```css
.table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc((100% / 5) - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.table-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
  <div class="table-item">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что приходит в голову - это вставить картинку в ячейку таблицы. Задав им желаемый размер.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td background="ссылка на изображение">Ячейка 1</td>
        <td>Ячейка 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```css
section{
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid  #dadada;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center; 
}

section div:first-child, section div:nth-child(2n+1) { 
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
}
section div:nth-child(2n) { 
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 40px;
}
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<section style="border: none;"><div> </div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/mPA1BK/teamspeak.png" alt="">
  </div> 
  <div><img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/mPA1BK/teamspeak.png" alt="">
  </div> 
  <div><img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/mPA1BK/teamspeak.png" alt="">
  </div> 
  <div><img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/mPA1BK/teamspeak.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>

<section>
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div> 
 <div></div>
</section>
```